# Converting SQL into Elasticsearch DSL for AND case

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-query

I have an SQL query like this

```
sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM dd_s3data WHERE (yelp_address = '370 Barren Rd' OR yelp_businessname ILIKE '%Computer%') AND (yelp_state = 'CT' OR yelp_category ILIKE '%flooring%');"
```

I am trying to convert it to Elasticsearch query. Here is the query I tried. It gives an `OR` result instead of `AND`

```
es_query1 = {
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {"match_phrase": {"yelp_address": "370 Barren Rd"}},
                        {"match": {"yelp_businessname": "Computer"}}
                    ],
                    "should": [
                        {"match": {"yelp_state": "CT"}},
                        {"match_phrase": {"yelp_category": "flooring"}}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have an even big query that I have to convert after my first query is correct.

```
sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM dd_s3data WHERE (yelp_address = '370 Barren Rd' OR yelp_businessname ILIKE '%Computer%') AND (yelp_state = 'CT' OR yelp_category ILIKE '%flooring%') AND yelp_noofreviews < 3.0 AND yelp_noofrating > 3.0;"
```

How to convert my SQL query, so that I get an `AND` result instead of `OR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "OR" you can use "should" with minimum_should_match:1

For "AND" you can use "must"

Filter is used if you don't want to calculate score for search result.
constant_score -returns every matching document with a relevance score equal to the boost parameter value.

In your case filter alone might be sufficient, if you want to use constant_score then wrap filter query with constant_score and use boost

**Query1:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match_phrase": {
                      "yelp_address": "370 Barren Rd"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "yelp_businessname": "Computer"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "minimum_should_match":1
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "yelp_state": "CT"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match_phrase": {
                      "yelp_category": "flooring"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "minimum_should_match":1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query2:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match_phrase": {
                      "yelp_address": "370 Barren Rd"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "yelp_businessname": "Computer"
                    }
                  }
                ]

              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "yelp_state": "CT"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match_phrase": {
                      "yelp_category": "flooring"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "minimum_should_match":1
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "yelp_noofreviews": {
                  "lt": 3
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "yelp_noofrating": {
                  "gt": 3
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```